# How to store gmail, name and google profile picture using Firebase Auth and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, navigation-drawer

I'm making an Android  application with FireBase and FireBaseAuth for Google Sign in. I have no user-table in my database, so FireBaseAuth doesn't do much other than authenticate the users.

I have a NavigationDrawer in the MainScreen (HomeScreen), where I wish to display the user's profile picture, name and email. Like this example (but with only 1 account / picture):

[image: Navigation Drawer example from Google Images]

The user is not Required to sign in to use the app, but some Activities (like Write a Review) requires a user to be signed in. If the user is not signed in, nothing has to be displayed about the user in the NavigationDrawer. However, if there is a signed in user, it's info should be displayed as in the example.

**Here is my FireBaseAuth code in ReviewActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reviews);

    //  Setting up the toolbar:
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Activity_Review_Toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Write a review");

    //  Setting up the database:
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    reviewDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Reviews");

    firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                // Already logged in
            }
            else {
                onSignedOutCleanup();
                // Not signed in
                startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .setAvailableProviders(
                            Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
                        .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

User sign-in works great, but my question is, how can I store a user's information, based on the Google information from FireBaseAuth? (I'm confident that I will have to create a User-model and a table for users).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are saving data on firebase realtime database.

**Step 1.Get user information from signup.**
I'm using a simple email and password. [Check the firebase auth docs for federated logins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)

**SignUpService**

```
public void signUpWithEmail(String email, String password) {
    this.firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            //Has the means to create a user (code step 3)
            UserService userService = new UserService();
            //A simple firebase user
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser =  task.getResult().getUser();
            //Your version of a user that is optionally converted from a firebase user                
            UserEntity userEntity =  userService.convertFirebaseUserToUser(firebaseUser);
            //create the user (code below)
            userService.create(userEntity).subscribe(reference -> Log.i(SignUpService.TAG, reference.toString()));

        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldnt sign user up");
        }

    });
    return;
}
```

**Step 2. (Optional) Convert FirebaseUser to a user that fits your business rules**

```
//Takes a firebase user and converts them into a user based on your business rules

public UserEntity convertFirebaseUserToUser(FirebaseUser firebaseUser)
{
UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setDisplayName(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
    userEntity.setEmail(firebaseUser.getEmail());
    userEntity.setDisplayPhoto(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
    userEntity.setKey(firebaseUser.getUid());
    return userEntity;
}
```

**3. Create the user**

```
/**
 * Takes a user entity and creates one
 * @param userEntity
 * @return
 */
public void create(UserEntity userEntity) {
    //initialise your backend
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    //retrieve the firebase key for the user you are about to add
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(BASE_PATH).push();
    String key = databaseReference.getKey();
    //create a user hashmap, with the user key as the hashmaps key, and the user entity as the value <K,V>
    Map<String, Object> userEntityHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    userEntityHashMap.put(key, userEntity);

    //create a listenner for your result
    DatabaseReference.CompletionListener completionListener = new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            //returns the reference to your newly created user
            if(databaseError != null) {
                //handle the incoming user creation error
            }
        }
    };
    databaseReference.setValue(userEntity, completionListener);
    return;
}
```

In my opinion a better way of doing this would be to have firebase cloud functions do this work for you on user sign up. If you're curious about moving the actual user profile fetching to your database without having to do it on your client, checkout the [authentication triggers for firebase cloud functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pADTJA3BoxE). It will push all that functionality to the firebase servers to do for you

Answer (score 0):

How usually its done, you will store it on the SharedPreference to store the user details such as firebaseToken, userId, firstname..etc